# Ascii or scancodes or some sort of keyboard input wher Backspace = 0x100

Tags: c, unix, keyboard, operating-system, xv6

Im working with XV6 MIT's Open Source OS .

Trying to figure out on what earth  can BACKSPACE = 0x100 ?
I want to add functions like right arrow and left arrow to control the console and i cant find the right numbers to capture them.
ex:

```
#define BACKSPACE 0x100 // given code
#define RIGHTARROW 0x99 //my addon 0x99 is not the right hex just an example   
if(c == RIGHTARROW){
     ....
    }
```

So my Q is on what table is BACKSPACE = 0x100 ? its not ASCII ... couldn't find it on scan-codes.
tried the showkeys command on Ubuntu and no luck.

anyone with a bit more experience or happened to do the MIT course of Operating system :)

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Have you tried capturing the keys your interested in and outputting the codes that you get?

Comment: Yea i tried something like that but all i could get out was that backspace get a char that its int is 256 ... couldnt match any more keys cause i cant seem to hit the correct ones , and if i print on every click the XV6 just wont run ( something to do with the startup sequence that uses that function im altering )

Comment: Ok managed to get this working with 228 and 229 ints , still dunno what table the original is using but until i do know ill use this ints and cast the c to int like so : (int)c = 228

Comment: What function are you using to set `c`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a custom character table.  0x100 is control + H, using the definition of 'H' and the control sequence: check out [console.c](https://github.com/maheshgondi/xv6/blob/master/console.c) in console_intr().  The table definition can be found in [kbd.h](https://github.com/maheshgondi/xv6/blob/master/kbd.h).  As you found LEFT is 0xE4 (and right 0xE5).